# If the suspensions of two simply connected spaces are homotopy equivalent, are the spaces homotopy equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are two CW complexes such that $\Sigma X$ and $\Sigma Y$ are homotopy equivalent, are the spaces $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent? I have seen a counterexample when $\pi_1(X)$ is not zero, so I am really looking for counterexamples where $X$ and $Y$ are $1$ connected.

Comment: Can you include the counter example you mention in your question? Or post it as an answer to your own question?

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Here is the link to the [counterexample](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11268/is-a-map-a-homotopy-equivalence-if-its-suspension-is-so?rq=1)
I have not looked at it closely but I think he gives  a counterexample to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spaces $\Sigma(S^n\times S^m)$ and $\Sigma\left(S^n\vee S^m\vee S^{m+n}\right) \cong S^{n+1}\vee S^{m+1}\vee S^{m+n+1}$ are homotopy eqiuvalent, while $S^n\times S^m$ and $S^n\vee S^m\vee S^{m+n}$ are not.

Comment: For the uninitiated, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301402/39599) gives an expression for the suspension of a product.